# Constraint to make width equal to another

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, snapkit

I've got a problem where I want a view (`indicatorView`)'s width equal to a button. I'm using `Snapkit` but I think this problem should be relevant with bare NSLayoutConstraint too. Here's what I'm doing to make `indicatorView's` width equal to `button`.

```
indicatorView.width.equalTo(button.snp.width)
```

However, this makes the button's width equal to the indicatorView's width, instead of making the indicatorView's width equal to buttons' width.

How can I specify the direction of the relation? Is that possible?

Comment: Are you referring to an `ActivityIndicatorView`?

Comment: A constraint like this is always bidirectional. It only says the two item have to have the same width. You have to setup an explicit width for your UIButton by a width constraint or by binding its edges.

Answer (score 1):

```
indicatorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
indicatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: button.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let f = indicatorView.frame
indicatorView.frame = CGRect(x: f.origin.x, y: f.origin.y: width: button.snp.width, height: f.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wrapping this in the correct closure? so it should look something like:

```
indicatorView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(button)
}
```